# Storing a class in a variable Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I want to pass a class as an argument so List changes dynamically, I've tried lots of things but none of them have worked out, I don't even know if it's actually possible in Java.

Any advice?

```java
 public class QueryMapper {

    protected Object targetClass;

    public QueryMapper(Object targetClass) {
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    public Object getTargetClass() {
        // targetClass;
        return targetClass.getClass();
    }

    public void setTargetClass(Object targetClass) {
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    public List<targetClass> mapper(Query q) {
        NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) q;

        nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
        List<Map<String, targetClass>> result = nativeQuery.getResultList();

        return q.getResultList();
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: This is possible using generics, but the code you have written now is not correct. See [tutorial on generics](https://dev.java/learn/generics/). Also: Please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank youu, I sorted  it out with generics :)